# PHP calculations in an array (recursive?)

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function that calculates the grand total price of each order, when given the price of the product and a credit that this user has. The credit should be deducted and if anything remains it should be deducted from the next order.

The function should return the final price of each order and the credits that remain foreach each account in **one single array** with the customer IDs as keys. Any negative numbers (credit or order prices) should all be set to 0.

'`abc`' and '`def`' are customer IDs. This sample code should explain things much better. **Do I need a recursive function for this?**

Input:

```
//should return: order 1 = 375, order 2 = 90, remaining credit = 0;
$order['abc'][1] = 500;
$order['abc'][2] = 90;
$credit['abc'] = 125;

//should return: order 1: 0, order 2: 0, remaining credit = 125
$order['def'][1] = 100;
$order['def'][2] = 75;
$credits['def'] = 300;
```

The return should be one single array, as such:

```
$set['abc'][1] = 375;
$set['abc'][2] = 90;
$set['abc']['credit_remaining'] = 0;
$set['def'][1] = 0;
$set['def'][2] = 0;
$set['def']['credit_remaining'] = 125;
```

Comment: Where's the code? What exactly do you have trouble with? No, you don't need recursion as you are not doing anything that involves doing itself as part of the solution. You also don't need code that knows anything about different customers, just one `function order_results($orders, $credit)`.

Comment: Jon, the customer ID's are required per the examples and specification in the question, otherwise you won't be able to associate any value with a specific customer. 

Stef, I am a bit confused to the purpose of this function as the requirements seem to be more for reporting than for an actual financial function? If we know this we may be able to offer a little more insight and better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for recursion, why not try something like this?

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($order as $customer => $value) 
{
    $newArray[$customer]['credit_remaining'] = $credit[$customer];

    foreach ($order[$customer] as $order_num => $cost) 
    {
        //Order is more than credit
        if($newArray[$customer]['credit_remaining'] - $order[$customer][order_num] <= 0)
        {
            $newArray[$customer][$order_num] = $order[$customer][$order_num] - newArray[$customer]['credit_remaining'];
            $newArray[$customer]['credit_remaining'] = 0;
        }

        //Otherwise
        else
        {
            $newArray[$customer]['credit_remaining'] -= $order[$customer][$order_num];
            $newArray[$customer][$order_num] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `$newArray[]...` on line 5. I fixed that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be recursive. This should work:

```
function someFunction( $order, $credit ) {
    $set = NULL;
    $keys = array_keys( $order );
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        $set[$key]['credit_remaining'] = $credit[$key];

        // assuming that the orders are numerically contiguous
        for ( $counter = 1; $counter < count( $order[$key] ); $counter++ ) {
            if ( $order[$key][$counter] < $set[$key]['credit_remaining'] ) {
                // then the order is less than the credit
                $set[$key]['credit_remaining'] -= $order[$key][$counter];
                $set[$key][$counter] = 0;
            } else {
                // not enough credit to cover this order
                $set[$key][$counter] -= $set[$key]['credit_remaining'];
                $set[$key]['credit_remaining'] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return $set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //should return: order 1 = 375, order 2 = 90, remaining credit = 0;
    $order['abc'][1] = 375; // assuming you meant 375 per your comment above
    $order['abc'][2] = 90;
    $credits['abc'] = 125; // assuming you meant $credits in the posted code

    //should return: order 1: 0, order 2: 0, remaining credit = 125
    $order['def'][1] = 100;
    $order['def'][2] = 75;
    $credits['def'] = 300;


    $set = array();
    foreach($order as $key=>$value){
            foreach($value as $single_order){
                    $set[$key][] = $single_order;
                    !isset($set[$key]['credit_remaining']) ? $set[$key]['credit_remaining'] = max(0,$credits[$key] - $single_order) : $set[$key]['credit_remaining'] = max(0,$set[$key]['credit_remaining'] - $single_order);
            }
            ksort($set[$key],SORT_STRING); // sort the array so the credits are last
    }

    print_r($set);

    /*
    Array
    (
        [abc] => Array
            (
                [0] => 375
                [1] => 90
                [credit_remaining] => 0
            )

        [def] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100
                [1] => 75
                [credit_remaining] => 125
            )

    )
    */
```